# SQLlite will rewrite my data on each call?

Tags: android

I want to add on my android app sql database. So my question is if i call and create my database on each time lets say i press a button, then will it have to create the database again from start along with tables and columns? Or will it check if the database exist then it will just fill the table with the rest of my info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataBase will be create only once.

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
    onCreate(db);
  }
```

here onCreate of the SqliteOpenHelper will get called only once unless we change the version of the Database.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Hope this is what you were looking for